# how to get a facebook status updates from certain fan page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, microsoft-metro, facebook-c#-sdk

Updated:1/27/2013
After some research I found out that I need to do a http get ..
I am using graph apis . I am using the below url .
How ever each time I am getting a bad request?
https://graph.facebook.com/1021259526/statuses&limit=20&access_token=AAAFM2GZAUaXQBAIlkFVUKxZCXs2rbZCuyoHy0n1jKucWuA8QorbdOLzJ7Wr3TUUBMrcZB6j008RjnOtwWnNJTcmzWSXZAjKeFz

I have assumed access token to be for user access token which I get every time a user logs in.

Is there any thin I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now able to get the json data .. For any one who gets stuck here I suggest you guys to use fiddler traces to capture the https traffic an duse that url in your app.... 
So my mistake here was https://graph.facebook.com/1021259526/statuses?method=GET&format=json&access_token="wahtever is teh access token" ....